# range sliders inverse propotional

Tags: slider, range

**Hi, I have two range slders i would like to make one reduce as the first one increases its for a project im doing for fun, thanks.**

```
<html>
<input type="range" min="-12" max="12" step="1" value="0" class="vslider" id="b1" />

<input type="range" min="-12" max="12" step="1" value="0" class="vslider" id="b2" />
   </html>
```

Comment: You could use JavaScript to achieve this: Write a function that increases or decreases the other slider at the `onChange` event of each slider. If you pass the other slider as function parameter you need only one function.

Answer (score 0):

````
```
<html>
<!--sum minimum to itself and double the max-->
<input type="range" min="0" max="24" step="1" 
         value="0" class="vslider" id="b1" />
    </html>



  ```
  ```
 <script>
 b1.oninput = function(evt){
 var dummy = 0;
 var minus = 0;

 var minus = parseFloat(evt.target.value);
//strip off decimal point if you like
  dummy = Math.round(minus-12);
//jam result in dummy var
//works for me
}
</script>

```
````